# How to detect/find Windows 8 current scale percentage

Tags: resources, windows-runtime, scaling

There are three scale percentages in Windows 8:
•100% when no scaling is applied
•140% for HD tablets
•180% for quad-XGA tablets

How can I detect in WinRT code what percentage the screen is at that moment?

(I want to make a custom image service that loads the best resolution from a database)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var currentScale = DisplayProperties.ResolutionScale;
```